# Reflecting C-style arrays with Boost Hana

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, reflection

`BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT` is a fantastic macro when declaring structures with introspection. If I have a structure like this:

```
struct Person {
  std::string name;
  std::string last_name;
  int age;
};
```

We can add introspection by redefining it like this:

```
struct Person {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
    (std::string, name),
    (std::string, last_name),
    (int, age)
  );
};
```

But what if we have a structure like this:

```
struct Person {
  float eye_dioptre[2];
};
```

How would I use the `BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT` syntax to reflect a C-style array?  I've tried:

```
struct Person {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person, 
    (float[2], eye_dioptre),   // error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
    (float, eye_dioptre[2])    // error: template argument 2 is invalid  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(structure_name, __VA_ARGS__ );                    
  );
};
```

Both options above give compiler errors.  The answer I'm expecting is "you should use c++-style arrays".  That could be done like so:

```
struct Person {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
    (std::array<float,2>, eye_dioptre)
  );
```

But is there a way to do it with C-style arrays?
    };

Comment: Maybe with previous `using`: `using float2 = float[2];` and then `(float2, eye_dioptre)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can think of is either by just using a pointer, which I presume you don't want, or using a [template alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), which would be something like:

```
template<size_t N>
using floatArr = float[N];
```

And when defining the `struct`:

```
struct Test {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Test,
        (floatArr<2>, example)
    );
};
```

An example program that illustrates this working: [[GCC]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2bKhg7xdqiIFxdvE)

In fact, you could even generalize this alias for any type as well:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
using CArray = T[N];
```

Now a C Style Array of any type can be used with `BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT` using a syntax such as `CArray<float, 2> example`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example.  This looks very similar to std::array.  Therefore I suspect that there isn't a way to reflect C-style arrays with boost hana.

Comment: @Stewart Yeah, there isn't, unfortunately.

Comment: `std::array` is a class, here, it is just an alias. so `eye_dioptre` is actually `float[2]`.